# mod_autoindex does not respect mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-autoindex

I have a directory structure similar to:

```
public_html/
  example.com/
    index.php
    subdir/
      file.jpg
```

I'm using shared hosting, so `http://example.com` maps to `/public_html/` for its root, and I can't change this. I've added a mod_rewrite rule to handle this issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ example\.com/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) example\.com/$1/ [L]
```

If I browse to `http://example.com/subdir` (without the trailing `/`) it will list *file.jpg* , but the URL for it will be `http://example.com/file.jpg`. The parent directory link is `http://example.com/example.com/`.

If I browse to `http://example.com/subdir/` (with the trailing `/`) it will list *file.jpg* with the proper URL: `http://example.com/subdir/file.jpg`. However, the parent directory link is `http://example.com/example.com/subdir/`.

I'm very confused for what's going on and I'd love any help on this.

(Note that if I take off the final `/` in the mod_rewrite rule then going to `http://example.com/subdir` without the `/` will redirect to the `http://example.com/example.com/subdir/` variant. Also, the parent directory for the listing at `http://example.com/subdir/` changes to `http://example.com/example.com/`, which is almost correct.)

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a disabled [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). So try to enable it or use this rule to do the same with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```